# Comparing raster - pixel colors using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, satellite

I would like to compare satellite pictures (raster) infra - red.

I have 2 rasters from the same area. I would like the compare pixels with the same xy coordinate using PyQGIS.

10 different values between the same= O and totaly different = 10.
10 different red colors.

So I can compare leaf green the state of the vegetation.

How do I start and which why to go?

Answer (score 2):

If you want compare values in 2 raster files, I recommend to use raster calculator in QGIS.

1. Load 2 rasters to QGIS
2. Raster -> Raster calculator
3. write `"B4@1" - "B5@1"` in Raster calculator expression area.
4. give any name for output layer
5. press`OK`

[image: raster calculator]
The above steps gives you a raster that values are differences of 2 rasters.
To obtain values of that raster at coordinates of points layer,

1. Open attribute table of points layer
2. Toggle to editing mode (Ctrl + E)
3. Open field calculator (Ctrl + I)
4. Write expression `raster_value('out',1,make_point($x, $y))`. `out` should be replace your created raster name.
5. press`OK`
   [image: field calculator]

You will get new laster layers values at each point in attribute table.